# Are these two equivalent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is a statement $ A=\left \{ a_1,..., a_n\right \}$ equivalent (perhaps, even by definition) to a statement  $A=\left \{ a:a=a_1\vee ... \vee a=a_n\right \}$? If it is, then it is quite strange they don't mention this in textbooks on set theory.

Comment: They don't mention it simply because it's trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. Most notably, neither of the statements implies that $A$ is an $n$-element set (we might have $a_1=a_2$, for example).

In formal (axiomatic) introductions, the Pairing axiom 
should be used to introduce the notation $\{a,b\}$ for the (unique) set $c$ with $z\in c\leftrightarrow (z=a\lor z=b)$.
They might in fact introduce $\{a\}$ as a shortcut for $\{a,a\}$.
And the notation $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ would in fact be too informal to be introduced at all.
Nevertheless, specifying a set by enumeration such as $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ is understood to mean precisely the set having precisely the elements listed, a notion that is also expressed by the other notation

Comment: Why is $\{a:a=a_1\lor a=a_2\}$ a set?

Comment: The set of elements $a$ such that $a=a_1$ or $a=a_2$.

Comment: @GustavoMarra Prove, using the axioms of $\sf ZFC$, that $\{a:a=a_1\lor a=a_2\}$ is a set. I assert the following: the notation $\{a:a=a_1\lor a=a_2\}$ is devoided of meaning by itself. It's short for something else, something that is formally correct. Until I understand exactly what $\{a:a=a_1\lor a=a_2\}$ means, I say the question is devoided of meaning.

Comment: Given a set $b$, the [axiom schema of specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) says that $\{a\in b: P(a)\}$, where $P$ is some unary property, is a set. The restriction to $b$ is essential. Considering entities such as $\{a:P(a)\}$ is what led to the [Russel's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).

Comment: @GitGud Many presentations of ZFC include the axiom of pairing, which says explicitly that, for any $x$ and $y$, there is a set with exactly $x$ and $y$ as its elements. Other presentations omit this axiom because it is redundant. Other axioms (either the axiom of infinity or the combination of the axiom of null set and the axiom of power set) provide a set with at least two elements, and from this one can obtain $\{x,y\}$ by the axom of replacement.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I have no problem with $\{a_1, a_2\}$, what I have a problem with is $\{a: a=a_1\lor a=a_2\}$.

Comment: @GitGud I use $\{a:a=a_1\lor a=a_2\}$ as the definition of $\{a_1,a_2\}$. Or, in more primitive notation, and in the standard form for definitions, $x=\{a_1,a_2\}\iff(\forall y)\,(y\in x\iff y=a_1\lor y=a_2)$.  I guess you must use a different definition of $\{a_1,a_2\}$; what is it?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I use the same as you. But using this definition, the  question is absolutely trivial.

Comment: @GitGud I completely agree; it's trivial.

Comment: In my answer I took for granted that $A:=\{\,a:\phi\,\}$ denotes the class with $a\in A\leftrightarrow \phi$. So what I really wanted to say is that $A$ is a set according to the Pairing axiom and that $\{x,y\}$ is in fact just a *notation* introduced on behalf of that; just like $P(a)$, $\bigcup a$, $\{\,x\in a\mid \phi\,\}$, $\{\,f(x)\mid x\in a\}$ are notations introduced for the sets whose existence is implied by the corresponding axioms (with uniqueness from Extension).